# set max date dynamicaly in jquery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I am try to implementing datepicker using jquery ,I want set max date of second datepicker is to selected date of first datepicker.

here is my code :-

```
        $('#firstDatePiker').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        startDate:""+currentdate,
         minDate: 0
        });

        $('#proofingDate').datetimepicker({
        dayOfWeekStart : 1,
        lang:'en',
        startDate:""+currentdate,
         minDate: 0,
        });
```

I have call function  `onblur` event on first datepiker  as follows:-

```
function addmaxDate()
{    
  var proDatetemp=$('#runDate').val();
  var maxDate = new Date(proDatetemp );
  $( "#proofingDate" ).datetimepicker( "option", "maxDate", maxDate );    
}
```

Comment: OK so what happens when you run the code, and what should happen instead? I.e. what is it that you are asking??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onShow` method of `datetimepicker`

```
$('#firstDatePiker').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: "" + currentdate,
    minDate: 0,
    onShow:function(ct){//current time
        this.setOptions({
            maxDate:$('#proofingDate').val()?$('#proofingDate').val():false
        })
    },
});

$('#proofingDate').datetimepicker({
    dayOfWeekStart: 1,
    lang: 'en',
    startDate: "" + currentdate,
    minDate: 0,
    onShow:function(ct){
         this.setOptions({
            maxDate:$('#firstDatePiker').val()?$('#firstDatePiker').val():false
         })
    },
});
```

Comment: i have tried this but it didn't work .I have use jquary UI date time picker. I want to following way    :-                                                                          run date( #firstDatePiker)  is not less than today's date. Also set the validation to proof date can't be greater than run date( #firstDatePiker) .